# Can I turn jQuery validate on/off in MVC web app with a separate jQuery event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC web application. In the form, the applicant can choose to add a co-applicant. If they choose to do so, elements of the co-applicant's information are required (ie, their first name, last name, email, etc.). I am using the jQuery Validate plugin to validate these text boxes.

Since the applicant does not need to include a co-applicant, I need to be able to the jQuery validate on these forms on and off. In other words, if the applicant chooses the button to add a co-applicant, the co-applicant information text boxes appear and these once hidden text boxes are now required.

Here is the code I tried to use, but it is not working.

HTML/MVC View:

```
<div class="form-group" id="coApplicantQuestion">
   <p>Would you like to add another person to this application?</p>
   <div class="col-md-10">
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(e => e.CoAppFlag, false, new { id = "CoApplicantRadioNo", @checked = "checked" })
       @Html.Label("CoApplicantRadioNo", "No")
       <br />
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(e => e.CoAppFlag, true, new { id = "CoApplicantRadioYes" })
       @Html.Label("CoApplicantRadioYes", "Yes")
   </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default" id="coApplicantInfo">
   <div class="panel-heading" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#CoApplicantInfoToggle">Co-Applicant Information</div>
        <div class="panel-body collapse in" id="CoApplicantInfoToggle">
            <form id="coApplicantPersonalInfo">
                   <div class="form-group">
                         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.App2FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                         <div class="col-md-10">
                               @Html.EditorFor(model => model.App2FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "coApplicantFirstName", @class = "form-control", Name = "coAppFirstName" } })
                               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.App2FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                          </div>
                   </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

The jQuery Validate:

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#CoApplicantRadioYes  input:radio').click(function () {
        $('#coApplicantPersonalInfo').validate({
            rules: {
                coAppFirstName: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            onfocusout: function (element) { $(element).valid(); },
            onkeyup: function (element) { $(element).valid(); }
        });
    });
 });
```

The only time the jQuery Validate code works is when I take it out of the click() event, however, this will not work for my application since these text boxes are only required if there is a co-applicant.

How do I make this work? Is this even possible with jQuery validate?

Comment: You're confused about how to use the `.validate()` method.  The `.validate()` method is only used to ***INITIALIZE*** the plugin on your form, not trigger validation.  It should not be inside your `click` handler.

Comment: Use conditional validation attributes, for example a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]`, or simply have the co-applicant's information properties as a separate complex property in your view model and then dynamically load the form controls for using ajax (and re-parse the validator) if required

Answer (score 0):

The best choice is creating jq function for activating validation and other function for deactivating. Use syntax like:

```
$('#MyId').rules('remove', 'required');
```

and for adding use:

```
$('#MyId').rules('add', 'required');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you show/hide controls based on the user's selection you can enable/disable those controls. [Disabled controls are skipped during validation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-fe-disabled)

```js
$("#CoApplicantRadioYes").click(function(){
 if($(this).is(":checked")){
  $("#RequiredBasedOnCheckbox :input").removeAttr("disabled");
 }
});

$("#CoApplicantRadioNo").click(function(){
 if($(this).is(":checked")){
     $("#RequiredBasedOnCheckbox :input").attr("disabled", "");
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="CoApplicantRadioYes" type="radio" name="test" checked />
  <input id="CoApplicantRadioNo" type="radio" name="test" />
  <div id="RequiredBasedOnCheckbox">
    <input type="text" required />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit
  </button>
</form>
```